# how to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable as a "local variable " belong to a specific program

Tags: linux

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a global variable which can affect all the program. Could I set it as a "local variable " belong to a specific program?

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you're after. Running `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/foo:/path/to/bar program` will only set that envvar for program and its children. Compiling the program with `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/foo` will bake a path into an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. There are no global variables, it is an environment variable. Environment variables are passed to child processes. The global-ness comes from it being set in the first (most-parent) process of your session.

## You can over-ride it.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=new_value program_to_run
```

or

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=new_value

program_to_run
another_program_to_run
```

The first form affects just one program, the second form affects latter programs in that shell.

or

```
(
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=new_value

  program_to_run
  another_program_to_run
)
back_to_normal
```

Comment: You also need `export` to your second and third version. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not magically exported.

Comment: @mosvy Is it not already an environment variable?

Comment: No. Why should it be?

Comment: I just tested it with the DISPLAY environment variable in `bash`, it dose (I would argue that it should not, but it does).